# How to programmatically open a console window on MacOS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I wonder, if it's possible to programmingly open a console window and redirect IO to it on MacOS X, similar to the `AllocConsole()`, `GetStdHandle()` APIs on Windows. I'm intending to use it in a xxx.app application, which doesn't come with any console window by default; I need to dynamically create one on the fly, in Obj-C.

Comment: Well, k, seems nobody cares about OSX.

Comment: so what you really want is a NSWindow to place debugging (or logging) output from `fprintf(stdout,` or stderr, or `cout <<` ?  Will this be a GUI app or a text/command line only app?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean to redirect stdout etc. It's a GUI app.