# Open Terminal/Console and bind stdout to it from C++ on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I have a shared library that gets loaded as a plugin from a third party application and I want to open a terminal/console window to see what gets written to stdout during debugging. On Windows I use [Visual C++ Enable Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2501968/6205379) to enable and bind the console. Now I want to do the same for macOS, how would I do that?

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780534/how-to-programmatically-open-a-console-window-on-macos-x but unfortunately it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to open a terminal during runtime or activate a console in your IDE (which one)?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I want to open the terminal during runtime so I have a live view of what's written to stdout in my process. The host application is a GUI app so I don't have a terminal by default.

Comment: If your app is GUI-based, then a terminal will not help you. Can't exactly remember, but in Macos' GUI-based apps stdout/stderr are automatically redirected to the console. Some old reference https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13992/macos-output-to-console-in-non-console-app

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn `Terminal.app` with a shell script you specify. So:

```
// Redirect stdout and stderr to a new temp file
char template[] = "/tmp/command_output_XXXXXX";
int fd = mkstemp(template);
dup2(fd, 1);
dup2(fd, 2);

// Prepare script
std::string command(template);
command += ".sh";

std::ofstream out(command);
out << "#!/bin/sh" << std::endl;
out << "exec /usr/bin/tail -f " << template << std::endl;
out.close();

// and go
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "open -a Terminal.app " << command;
system(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Good idea. The problem is though that the shell script won't work if you have PowerShell Core as default shell (coming from Windows, many devs in my company will set PSCore as default shell because they're used to it). I tried to use AppleScript instead with `tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "..."` but I couldn't get that working either.

Comment: Can I somehow start the terminal app with a specific shell? I couldn't find any command line args for the app itself. Something like `open -a Terminal.app -- --shell sh`.

Comment: Just a guess, but try setting the `SHELL` environment variable?

Comment: Hmm `open -Fna Terminal.app --env SHELL=/bin/sh` didn't do anything. Terminal still launched with powershell.

Comment: No idea then. You might have better luck asking a new question.